# How to install Apache server in GCE VM instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I tried to install apache server in GCE VM by these commands:

```
sudo docker pull httpd
sudo docker run -d --name apache-server -p 86:80 httpd                          
sudo docker container start apache-server
```

But when I try to hit the port `http://34.138.232.98:86/`, I get the following:

```
Welcome to nginx!
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.
```

I installed the `Apache` but getting `NGINX`, not able to understand what exactly happened here.

Comment: Is the IP of the VM that you reach? Can you detail more your set up to help us to reproduce the same issue?

Comment: Looks like there's another http server running in your container. Try creating a new VM and run commands `sudo docker pull httpd` & `sudo docker run -d --name apache-server -p 86:80 httpd` only. `docker run` starts the container so you don't need to `docker start` it. Try fresh VM (ideally Container Optimised OS). You can always install the Apache directly on the VM if that's the only thing that you need to run on it.

Comment: I deleted the vm and performed the same steps again. This time it worked. But could not find the cause though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's another http server running in your container that blocks the port.

Try creating a new VM and run commands `sudo docker pull httpd` & `sudo docker run -d --name apache-server -p 86:80 httpd` only.

`docker run` starts the container so you don't need to docker start it.

Try fresh VM (ideally Container Optimised OS). You can always install the Apache directly on the VM if that's the only thing that you need to run on it with `sudo apt install apache2 -y` and allow http traffic in your VM's firewall with `sudo ufw allow 'WWW'`.

Make sure also that your [GPS's firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) allows traffic in & out.